# Удалить повторы из QuerySet Django

Tags: python, django, queryset

model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    mytags = models.ManyToManyField ('Tag', blank=True, verbose_name= 'теги')

class Tag(models.Model):
    mytags = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mytags
```

views

```
@page_template('blog/tags.html')
def search_by_tag(request, mytags_per, template='blog/post_list.html',extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'tags_piu': Post.objects.filter(mytags__mytags__in=[mytags_per]).distinct(),
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return render(request, template, context)
```

и сам html

```
{% for post in tags_piu %}
    {% for mytags in post.mytags.all %}

          <a href="{% url 'post_tags' mytags_per=mytags %}" id="tags-w">
            {{ mytags }}
          </a>

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

есть несколько статей с повторяющимися полями-- получаем -- tank tank jat jat
как убрать повторы??

Answer (score 4):

Можно [зарегистрировать несколько фильтров](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def values(items, attr_name):
    return [getattr(i, attr_name) for i in items]


@register.filter()
def distinct(items):
    return set(items)


@register.filter()
def qs_distinct(qs, field_names):
    fields = map(str.strip, fields_names.split(','))
    return qs.order_by(*fields).distinct(*fields)
```

И пользоваться ими в шаблоне так

```
{% for tag in post.mytags.all|values:'mytags'|distinct %}
```

или так

```
{% for tag in post.mytags.all|qs_distinct:'mytags' %}
```

Comment: Спасибо Сергей, Вы очень помогли, мне осталось разобраться как добавить данные теги :)

Comment: странно но почему-то не работает , ошибок никаких нет, но без изменений, попробовал оба варианта, подключил теги через {% load %}

Comment: Может быть проблема не в механизмах, а в алгоритме? Что именно вы пытаетесь вывести? Все теги постов, содержащих определённый тег? Если да, то дубликаты неизбежны в силу логики.

Comment: есть допустим 10 статей, каждой статье присвоено своё поле с тегами согласно модели, и когда я их все вывожу на странице, некоторые из них повторяются.  --- было бы не плохо если бы цикл  for прошёлся по статьям вынул теги из всех постов, сложил их между собой и поместил всё в список, а потом вывел через set()

Comment: Тогда это надо делать не в шаблоне, а в представлении - получать список постов вместе с тегами, формировать из полученного множество тегов без повторений и передавать в шаблон.

Answer (score 1):

А distinct по первичному ключу точно не помогает?

```
Post.objects.filter(mytags__mytags__in=[mytags_per]).distinct('pk')
```

Comment: У автора повторы не постов, а тегов возникают.